# Microsoft Bot Connector - get activity id from response after sending message

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm working on a bot for MS Teams using Microsoft's bot framework (using the .NET API). What I am trying to do right now is to retrieve the [`Activity.Id`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-identifiers-guide#activity-id) of a message the bot has just sent.  When the bot receives a message, an `Activity.Id` is included and I was hoping there was a way to retrieve that when sending a message.

I am currently sending using:
`var response = connector.Conversations.SendToConversation((Activity)activity);`

`connector` being an instance of `Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConnectorClient`

This returns a [`ResourceResponse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.connector.resourceresponse?view=botconnector-3.12.2.4), which contains an Id, but this Id does not appear to be in the same format as that of the Activity.Id that comes with a message received.

Does anyone know if it is possible to get this information?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at CreateConversationAsync. Here's a code snippet taken from our [C# complete sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-csharp/blob/17ccfeeb59034544bb2e5c2fb227dfb2892f8f7f/template-bot-master-csharp/src/dialogs/examples/teams/ProactiveMsgTo1to1Dialog.cs):

```
        try
        {
            var conversationResource = await connectorClient.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(parameters);
            IMessageActivity message = null;

            if (conversationResource != null)
            {
                message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
                message.From = new ChannelAccount(botId, botName);
                message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: conversationResource.Id.ToString());
                message.Text = Strings.Send1on1Prompt;
            }

            await connectorClient.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just using the ResourceResponse.Id value as it serves my purposes well enough.

Comment: @David - the resourceResponse id ? thats not an activity id? so when you later want to reply to this message, what do you then do? When i use ReplyToActivityAsync to this id, the message is not a reply to but instead its just a new message in the channel

Answer (score 0):

What about saving the user activity and save the last activity id sent to user, and retrieve it when he sends a message again .to know more about saving user activity see this article Visit: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/05/05/saving-bot-actions-on-azure-sql-server/

I hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just using the ResourceResponse.Id value as it serves my purposes well enough.

Comment: @David - Can you please elaborate? What did you do? What purpose does the `ResourceResponse.Id` serve?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Since this is a 1on1 conversation, and replying to individual messages is not a thing, in the end it really doesn't serve much of a purpose beyond providing a unique identifier in the database for my code to reference (i.e. to check whether or not a reminder has been sent).  Is that the information you're looking for?