# How to send out of turn messages and replies in bot builder framework 4.0

Tags: c#, botframework

I am (on external events) posting messages to my microsoft team channel.

```
var activity = new Activity("message", text: $"", attachments: new List<Microsoft.Bot.Schema.Attachment>
    {
        new Microsoft.Bot.Schema.Attachment{ ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive" , Content= new JRaw(json)}
    });
var a = await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync("hardcoded channel string, cant find it anywhere",
    activity);
```

Which works, the adaptive card is shown in my channel.

I now want to follow up with an reply to this activity later.

```
 var b = await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync("same channel id hardcoded", a.Id, new Activity("message", text: "user disconected",replyToId : a.Id));
```

but the message is not shown as a reply but instead just a new message in the channel.

The id returned from response of SendToConversationAsync, do not look like an activity id, so how do i get the activity id such i can reply to it properly.

The connectorClient is created like:

```
var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri("https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/"), appCredentials);
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say "the message is not shown as a reply but instead just a new message in the channel"? What does it mean for a message to be shown "as a reply"? What is happening versus what are you expecting to happen? Do you mean the bot starts a new conversation with its own history without the other conversation's history being visible? My understand of Teams is that there's only one conversation between any two given users

Comment: In teams, when the message is a reply its nested below (within the box/frame) of the original message that it was replied to. When there are many replies it will collaps them and "show all replies". In channels, its like a chat room where you can reply to specific messages and it groups them. You are talking about one to one chats i think.

Comment: Ah, yes I was. I see what you mean now

Comment: Are you still working on this issue?

Comment: I have not found a solution to this no.

Comment: Can you include the code you're using to set your `connector` variable?

Comment: Updated,  but as written, the reponded id do not look like an activity id, so question is if its possible to get the activity id from a teams message. Bill also said no on twitter: https://twitter.com/bill_bliss/status/1069251683958480896

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this sample to see how to send proactive messages in BotBuilder V4: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages

Of particular interest should be the [CompleteJobAsync method](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages/ProactiveBot.cs#L214):

```
// Sends a proactive message to the user.
private async Task CompleteJobAsync(
    BotAdapter adapter,
    string botId,
    JobLog.JobData jobInfo,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    await adapter.ContinueConversationAsync(botId, jobInfo.Conversation, CreateCallback(jobInfo), cancellationToken);
}
```

From this we can see that the trick is to use [BotAdapter.ContinueConversationAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.botadapter.continueconversationasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_BotAdapter_ContinueConversationAsync_System_String_Microsoft_Bot_Schema_ConversationReference_Microsoft_Bot_Builder_BotCallbackHandler_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

I've tested this in Teams and found that it will live up to its name by continuing the conversation rather than starting a new one.

---

EDIT: I now understand that you meant to ask something more like this question: [Microsoft Bot Connector - get activity id from response after sending message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457824/microsoft-bot-connector-get-activity-id-from-response-after-sending-message)

That is to say, you understand that in a Microsoft Teams team channel, all activities will share the same "root" conversation ID that looks like this: `19:ad2f5f5a246241718826833354894656@thread.skype`

And each "thread" will have its own conversation ID that consists of the root ID plus the message ID that started the thread: `19:ad2f5f5a246241718826833354894656@thread.skype;messageid=1545970892795`

So if you want to start a new thread then you can send a message to the root conversation ID and if you want to reply to a thread then you can send a message to the thread's conversation ID. In this regard, there's no difference between `SendToConversationAsync` and `ReplyToActivityAsync` because, despite appearances, Teams doesn't "nest" messages under other messages. Instead, each message chain is identified by its own conversation ID.

So in order to send a message to a thread, you've discovered that you need to know the ID of the message that started the thread. Unfortunately, the ID returned by `SendToConversationAsync` and `ReplyToActivityAsync` is in a different form from the one you need. After extensive testing I've discovered that Teams seems to have two forms of message ID:

- Epoch timestamps (1545970800530)

  - Used as the activity ID in messages sent to the bot
  - Used as part of a conversation ID to define a thread (19:ad2f5f5a246241718826833354894656@thread.skype;messageid=1545970892795)
- Alphanumeric codes (1:1zDTpbvf1DFFLC5cL0n72d-wPdIIV2L6L5LZ5H_nzqhs)

  - Returned as HTTP content from calls to the REST API
  - Used for updating and presumably for deleting activities

So are you out of luck? Not at all! It turns out that if you create the thread with `CreateConversationAsync` then it will return the thread's conversation ID which you can use for your replies. Here is an extension class to make it easy for you:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams.Models;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;

namespace Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams
{
    public static class TeamsExtensions
    {
        public static async Task<ConversationResourceResponse> CreateTeamsThreadAsync(
            this ITurnContext turnContext,
            Activity activity,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            var connectorClient = turnContext.TurnState.Get<IConnectorClient>() as ConnectorClient;
            activity.ChannelData = turnContext.Activity.ChannelData;

            return await connectorClient.Conversations.CreateTeamsThreadAsync(turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id, activity, cancellationToken);
        }

        public static async Task<ConversationResourceResponse> CreateTeamsThreadAsync(
            this IConversations conversations,
            string conversationId,
            Activity activity,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            var channelData = activity.GetChannelData<TeamsChannelData>();

            var parameters = new ConversationParameters
            {
                ChannelData = new TeamsChannelData
                {
                    Channel = channelData.Channel,
                    Team = channelData.Team,
                    Tenant = channelData.Tenant,
                },
                Activity = activity,
            };

            return await conversations.CreateConversationAsync(parameters, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Since I saw that you already have a `ConnectorClient` and a conversation ID I made a method that uses those. You can also call the method that extends `ITurnContext` if you're want to create a thread in response to a message from a user. All you have to do is save the `Id` value of the `ConversationResourceResponse` that the method returns so you can use it for your proactive messages.

[image: Bot replying to itself]

Comment: is that for 1 to 1 conversations between bot and person? or does it work in team channels such it replies to existing messages from the past?  I think i already was down that road, but will try again. maybe i did somethign wrong.

Comment: I read the code and think that it works becaues the user initiated the conversation by scheduling a job and it can reply to this everything.  My case, the bot writes the first message - then it dont think it works? I need to verify

Comment: I was testing in a conversation in a Teams channel, yes. Not a 1 to 1.

Comment: So are you saying you want the bot to start a conversation and then reply to that same conversation without any users necessarily replying, as though the bot is having a conversation with itself? Can you post more code that pertains to how your bot is initiating the conversation from an external event, such that someone could reproduce your problem?

Comment: Yes exactly, sorry that it was not clear. The code is exactly whats in the question. The a = SendToConversationAsync to a channel in teams with an activty ( i used an adaptive card).  Then when trying to reply with b= ReplyToActivityAsync - here the problem is that the returned reference a.id is not a real activity id and therefore it properly creates a new message and not a reply.   I dont know how to create a better example without putting in all the channel ids and such? Do you still need me to do a better example?

Comment: At least explain how you're getting the channel ID's. Your code also doesn't mention how these events are being generated or responded to.

Comment: I wrote to the bot in debug mode and copy pasted the channelid out and hardcoded it the code.   The events are just a signalr hub when people are connecting. Could be anything, could just be a console app that runs for demostration purpose. Maybe that would be a good example actually, i will try to make a small console app that does it all and put on github

Comment: Did you ever get around to making the console app?

Comment: Sorry, no- Christmas came around and i forgot all about it. I will try to get it done in the coming days.

Comment: No need, I already managed to find a solution. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I will give it a spin and hopefully get to the same conclussion.